# How to resolve "module is not defined."

Tags: jshint

I have a module that I'm using elsewhere, but I keep getting "module is not defined." It works if I use the global directive but that implies that the module is defined elsewhere. Is there any way to fix this issue? Thank you

In `module.js`

```
/* exported module */
var module = (function($){
   ...
   return {method: method};
})($);
$(module.method);
```

In `foo.js`

```
var foo = function() {
     function bar() {
         module.method();
     }
};
$(foo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do the following in your jshint.rc

```
 "jshint_options":
    {
        "globals": {
            "module": false
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case didn't work, thus, I injected next piece of code:

```
/* globals module: false */
```

Answer (score 2):

We get this error whenever we `"use strict";` mode in `Node.js` project. Just add the given below option in your `.jshintrc` file to fix it:

```
{
  "node": true
}
```

This way jshint will know you are working in `Node.js` environment.